# Savon on Rails 3.1- Can not call a method using WSDL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wsdl, savon

I want to use a webservice with a method "verifyTransaction" that get two strings as input and return a double as output.
I used the code below for that:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do |wsdl|
    wsdl.document = "https://www.myserver.com/ReferencePayment?WSDL"
end

response = client.request :wsdl, "verifyTransaction" do
  soap.body ={"RefNum" => "121312", "MerchantID" => "02233763"}
end
```

but the I got this error:

```
Savon::SOAP::Fault ((env:Client) caught exception while handling request: unexpected encoding style: expected=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, actual=)
```

I've been reading all the resources on web but I couldn't find any solutions. 
Please help me with this.

Comment: It seems the WSDL you are trying to download does not have the expected format?

Comment: What's the expected format for the wsdl? I'm pretty sure that the WSDL should be fine. It's from a financial institution and many users are already using it.

Comment: without WSDL it's almost impossible to help you. Is there a public URL available?

Comment: it's https://acquirer.sb24.com/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using SoapUI and Savon.

I've opened the WSDL in SoapUI, generate a sample requests and copy/paste it into Savon like this:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do |wsdl|
    wsdl.document = "https://acquirer.sb24.com/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL"
end

response = client.request "verifyTransaction" do
  soap.xml = 'XML will be here'
end
```

It worked fine! :)